# For Loop: Skip to next line after X seconds

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, terminate

Can someone help me with this code:

I have a dataGrid with 2 columns:
[image: My grid]

and what I want to do is use PStools' Psloggedon cmd to give me the name of every person logged in and append that result to the "LOGGED_IN" column but what is happening is that if there is no user logged into a PC, the process takes like 5 minutes to post an error message.

Now, what I want to do is that if .5 seconds has gone to just forget the row it's currently querying and move on to the next row, in the column?

here is the `vb.net` code i want to focus on:

```
  Dim RowCount As Integer = datagridView1.RowCount  
  For i = 0 To RowCount - 2
        'PERFORM PSLOGGEDON ROUTINE
        Dim Proc1 As New Process
        Proc1.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("psloggedon")
        Proc1.StartInfo.Arguments = "-l \\" & datagridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value & ""
        Proc1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        Proc1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        Proc1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        Proc1.Start()

        'INSERT RESULTS IN LOGGEN_IN COLUMN
        datagridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = Proc1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd
    Next
```

Can someone please show me how to write the code to get that done?

Comment: Can you step through the code? Which line is taking a long time to execute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Process.WaitForExit(int milliseconds)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0d8k56%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

> Instructs the Process component to wait the specified number of milliseconds for the associated process to exit.
>
> **Return Value**
>   Type: `System.Boolean`
>   `true` if the associated process has exited; otherwise, `false`.

You can then use `Process.Kill` to kill process if it did not exit in given time.

Something like

```
Dim RowCount As Integer = datagridView1.RowCount  
For i = 0 To RowCount - 2
    'PERFORM PSLOGGEDON ROUTINE
    Dim Proc1 As New Process
    Proc1.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("psloggedon")
    Proc1.StartInfo.Arguments = "-l \\" & datagridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value & ""
    Proc1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    Proc1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    Proc1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    Proc1.Start()

    If Not Proc1.WaitForExit(5000) Then
        Proc1.Kill()
    End If

    'INSERT RESULTS IN LOGGEN_IN COLUMN
    datagridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = Proc1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd
Next
```

Comment: I tried it and got this error:  
"Win32Exception was unhandled  
Access is denied"  

what could be causing this? admin rights?